# enterDecision(int) in the type DebugEventListener is not applicable for the arguments (int, boolean)？

Tags: antlr

I am using ANTLR 3.1.3 to generate the parser. After importing the generated testParser, I found there is several errors like

try { dbg.enterDecision(2, decisionCanBacktrack[2]);

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method enterDecision(int) in the type DebugEventListener is not applicable for the arguments (int, boolean) testParser.java /ANTLRTest/src  line 280    Java Problem

If I changed to  dbg.enterDecision(2), then everything is fine.

The grammar is as follows,

```
grammar Test;  

options {output=AST;}

expr : mexpr (PLUS^ mexpr)* SEMI! ; 

mexpr : atom (STAR^ atom)* ;  
atom: INT ;  
//class csharpTestLexer extends Lexer;  
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r') { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;  
LPAREN: '(' ;  
RPAREN: ')' ;  
STAR: '*' ;  
PLUS: '+' ;  
SEMI: ';' ; 

DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;  
INT : (DIGIT)+ ;
```

I am using ANTLRWorks 1.4.3 to generate lexer and parser.

JDK 1.6

Any reason to this error?

Comment: I have options { output=AST} defined

Comment: I found that when I use Generate/generate Code, then the generated lexer/parser is fine. But if I use debug which also generate the code, the code cannot coompile

Comment: Probably under ANTLRWorks, there are some dbg embedded. I do not see this when I use Generate Code.

Comment: Just import the code into Eclipse and I get the error. It works fine if running under ANTLRWorks. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: BTW, I get error for 2 + 2 * 3, do you know why? anything wrong with the above grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've generated a lexer and parser with an ANTLR version that is different than the one you added to Eclipse's classpath.

If you generate a lexer and/or parser with ANTLRWorks 1.4.3 (which contains ANTLR 3.4), you should  also add ANTLR 3.4 to your project's build path in Eclipse and remove ANTLR 3.1.3 from it.

> BTW, I get error for 2 + 2 * 3, do you know why? anything wrong with the above grammar.

That is because single digit numbers are being tokenized as `DIGIT` tokens. Either make `DIGIT` a fragment:

```
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;  
INT : (DIGIT)+ ;
```

or remove it:

```
INT : '0'..'9'+ ;
```

See: [What does "fragment" mean in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487593/what-does-fragment-means-in-antlr)

Comment: I am still not sure why: when not using fragment, 2+2*3 is wrong, but 22 + 22 * 33 is correct, can you clarify?

Comment: @AdamLee, if `DIGIT` isn't a `fragment`, then the input `2+2*3` causes the lexer  to produce the tokens: `DIGIT STAR DIGIT STAR DIGIT`. Your parser cannot match these tokens, *it* can only make something of the tokens `INT STAR INT STAR INT`. If you make `DIGIT` a `fragment`, then the lexer will never create `DIGIT` tokens: `fragment` rules are only used by other lexer rules (`INT` in your case) and never become tokens of their own.

Comment: @AdamLee, the fact that `"22"` is tokenized as an `INT`, and `"2"` as a `DIGIT` is because whenever two or more rules match the same input (both `DIGIT` and `INT` match `"2"`), the one defined first "wins" (`DIGIT` in your case). Note that from `"22"` an `INT` is created because it's more than a single digit!