# many multiple alternatives errors with my C grammar

Tags: c, antlr, grammar, rule

I am trying to write a C grammar with Antlwork, and for that I used this one http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/antlr_v3.2/examples-v3/java/C/C.g where I tried  to make it more simple by removing many blocks I don't use and the backtracking. And here is what I have : http://www.archive-host.com/files/1956778/24fe084677d7655eb57ba66e1864081450017dd9/CNew.txt

Then when I do ctrl+D, I get a lot of warning and errors like these:

```
[21:20:54] warning(200): C:\CNew.g:188:2:  Decision can match input such as "'{' '}'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
[21:20:54] warning(200): C:\CNew.g:210:2: Decision can match input such as "'for' '('" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3
As a result, alternative(s) 3 were disabled for that input
[21:20:54] error(201): C:\CNew.g:210:2: The following alternatives can never be matched: 3

[21:20:54] error(208): C:\CNew.g:250:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: CHAR
```

I don't really understand why I have all these warnings, there should not be conflicts.

Comment: Then don't remove the `backtrack` (and `memoize`) options.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but a friend told me that using backtrack would cause me later many difficulties when I will try to do the AST.

Comment: You have 2 options here: `1)` either rewrite the grammar so that the ambiguities are no longer there (which is probably quite hard, seeing you started with a grammar that had backtracking enabled), or `2)` re-enable backtracking. Ask your friend what exactly s/he meant by *"many difficulties when I will try to do the AST"*, because it sounds like non-sense. There's no problem creating an AST from a parser grammar that has backtracking enabled.

Comment: well when I did the grammar, I modified a lot of blocks so that it would fit even without the backtrack, or that is what I thought but since I am beginner, I must have missed many things. As for the backtrack he told me that it would create a lot of nodes wich may burden a lot the parser and the compilator wich i will try to write with this grammar. But it is true that with the backtrack I don't have any warnings anymore, but I still have this error

Comment: [22:02:55] error(208): C:\Users\Seiya\Desktop\projets\TRAD\Gram\CNew.g:238:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: CONSTANT
[22:17:18] error(208): CNew.g:251:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: CHAR
[22:17:18] error(208): C:\Users\Seiya\Desktop\projets\TRAD\Gram\CNew.g:251:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: CHAR

Comment: Having a lot of nodes shouldn't burden the parser, I wouldn't think.

Comment: @KyleStrand, the generated AST would not contain any more nodes whether backtracking is enabled or disabled.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarifications, I will try to do with the backtrack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I still have this error
>
> [22:02:55] error(208): C:\Users\Seiya\Desktop\projets\TRAD\Gram\CNew.g:238:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: CONSTANT [22:17:18] error(208): CNew.g:251:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: CHAR [22:17:18] error(208): C:\Users\Seiya\Desktop\projets\TRAD\Gram\CNew.g:251:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: CHAR

That means the lexer can never create the tokens `CHAR` and `INT` because some other lexer rule, `CONSTANT`, matches the same input. What you need to do is change `CONSTANT` into a parser rule.

In other words, change these two rules:

```
primary_expression
    : ID
    | CONSTANT
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

CONSTANT
    :   INT
    |   CHAR
    ;
```

into the following:

```
primary_expression
    : ID
    | constant
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;

constant
    :   INT
    |   CHAR
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but does that mean that in a lexer rule definition you can't use another one ? here is what i have http://i.imgur.com/7EnFgRu.jpg
At the left I have a red subtree I suppose it means there is ambiguities . And just below the : (external_declaration)+ line, the ";" caractere is in red . Is it bad ?

Comment: @Exia0890, yes, a lexer rule can use another lexer rule. But how you set it up, the lexer could never have created `INT` and `CHAR` tokens since a `CONSTANT` **always** would have been created. You either had to make `INT` and `CHAR` fragment-rules, or "promote" `CONSTANT` to a parser rule (the latter being more appropriate, hence my recommendation). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487593/what-does-fragment-means-in-antlr

Comment: The red in your image is a (partial) parse that the parser has given up on since it could not complete said parse. The parser backtracked from the `function_definition` rule to match the `declaration` rule.

Comment: I see, thanks, I did not know about the fragment-rule it is pretty useful too.