# Antlr grammar won't work

Tags: antlr

My grammar won't accept inputs like  "x = 4, xy = 1"

```
grammar Ex5;

prog : stat+;
stat : ID '=' NUMBER;

LETTER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
DIGIT : ('0'..'9');
ID : LETTER+;
NUMBER : DIGIT+;
WS : (' '|'\t'| '\r'? '\n' )+ {skip();};
```

What do i have to do to make it accept a multitude of inputs like ID = NUMBER??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to account for the comma, `','`, inside your grammar. Also, since you (most probably) don't want `LETTER` and `DIGIT` tokens to be created since they are only used in other lexer rules, you should make these [`fragments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487593/what-does-fragment-means-in-antlr):

```
grammar Ex5;

prog : stat (',' stat)*;
stat : ID '=' NUMBER;

ID     : LETTER+;
NUMBER : DIGIT+;

fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9';

WS : (' '|'\t'| '\r'? '\n')+ {skip();};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not take in account the comma, and i will check what fragment is.