# Antlr grammar, implicit token definition in parser rule

Tags: parsing, antlr, token, definition, implicit

A weird thing is going on. I defined the grammar and this is an excerpt.

```
name  
   : Letter                 
   | Digit name              
   | Letter name          
   ;

numeral  
   : Digit                
   | Digit numeral         
   ;

fragment  
Digit  
   : [0-9]  
   ;  

fragment  
Letter  
   : [a-zA-Z]  
   ;
```

So why does it show warnings for just two lines (Letter and Digit name) where i referenced a fragment and others below are completely fine...

Comment: please show us your code, so we can help you

Comment: What warnings do you get?

Comment: just one
warning(125): implicit definition of token 'Letter' in parser .....   
and then for the digit in Digit name line it says the same with 'Digit'..
Implicit token definition in parser rule

Comment: So i just erased the fragment lines and there are no errors. Is this ok, will it do the right thing now?

Answer (score 8):

Lexer rules you mark as `fragment`s can only be used by other lexer rules, not by parser rules. Fragment rules never become a token of their own.

Be sure you understand the difference: [What does "fragment" mean in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487593/what-does-fragment-means-in-antlr)

### EDIT

Also, I now see that you're doing too much in the parser. The rules `name` and `numeral` should really be a lexer rule:

```
Name
 : ( Digit | Letter)* Letter
 ;

Numeral
 : Digit+
 ;
```

in which case you don't need to account for a `Space` rule in any of your parser rules (this is about your last question which was just removed).

Comment: I used the C grammar as an example. Here : https://github.com/gavransava/grammars-v4/commit/15df18159653f7ae2963cc73bec7d2b8939a9363#diff-74edde23ba1382b96fb11735598f5dacR503

... And you are right, there is an Identifier rule which is not a fragment, it is used in parser rules, but is not a fragment itself. But it still contains fragment in its own definition..

Comment: @SavaGavran, also check my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are using an older version of antlr:
[0-9]

and

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

are not valid regular expressions in old Antlr.
replace them with

```
'0'..'9'
```

and

```
('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')
```

and your issues should go away.

Comment: In ANTLRv4 now they are valid expressions, see https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/JavaLexer.g4#L207